# Page is briefly unstyled in NextJS production?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, css-modules

I'm working with NextJS and am currently looking at deployment. However, after running `npm run build` to see the production version of the website, I find that some pages are momentarily unstyled (text, image size). The images and text are fetched using `getServerSideProps`, where I make a request to my API. Why is this and how can I fix it?

I am importing my CSS modules as follows in the problematic pages:

```js
import styles from "../../styles/Item.module.css";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17086

Comment: @felixmosh Any fixes so far?

Comment: There is my PR which solves it, but It don't get the maintainers attention.

Comment: @felixmosh Any workaround you could provide without the PR approval?

Comment: You can patch the lib with patch-package or something like that